# 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can someone help me with this Hausdorff measure question? I'm self learning graduate Real Analysis and I don't know how to type notations so I just take pic of the question.

[image]

Comment: You should try to write out the question as best you can.  People will be (relatively) happy to help you learn to do so.

Comment: You can type things like X = \mathbb{R} and \mathcal{H}_1([a,b]) but enclose them in dollar signs to get notation that looks like the picture.

Comment: People will try to help you with a picture too, but if you'd like to learn how to write math font, here is [the site primer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)